# Handling boolean values from ORC file with Trino

Tags: python, hive, presto, trino

I have a python df which has boolean columns in it. This df is written to ORC file format and stored in hdfs. Taking this as external location, I am trying to create hive table using Trino. But the boolean values are not properly loading I see nulls in the table. Any suggestions on how I can over come this.

Tried converting the data types in df to string and int before converting it into ORC file. Still it is showing nulls.